# BigQuery how to pass shell commandline parameters to sql file

Tags: shell, google-bigquery, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass a shell commandline parameter into a SQL file that I'm executing in BigQuery.  I keep getting this error and can't figure out how to resolve it:

`Unexpected macro at [1:14]`

Here is the shell script I am executing (`install.sh`):

```
do
    case "${flag}" in
        p) project=${OPTARG};;
        d) dataset=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done
echo $project
echo $dataset


gcloud config set project $project

bq query --flagfile=./test/ddl_table.sql
```

Here is the `ddl_table.sql` file:

```
CREATE TABLE $dataset.my_table (
    metric_sk INT64,
    metric_identifier STRING ,
    metric_name STRING ,
    metric_def STRING ,
    metric_type_id INT64 
);
```

And here is the command I'm using to execute the .sh file:

```
./install.sh -p 'my_project' -d 'my_dataset'
```

The `echo` commands reflect that the parameters have been correctly set, but the reference to `$dataset` in the SQL file seems to be problematic.  The character at line 1 column 14 (as indicated by the error message) is the `$` character.  So it seems BigQuery doesn't recognize that as a parameter.  I can't figure out how to resolve this.  I would like the dataset name to be determined by the parameter passed in from the commandline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based from the [Running parameterized queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries) document of Google Cloud:

> Parameters cannot be used as substitutes for identifiers, column names, table names, or other parts of the query.

As I understand this, you can use parameters within the essential SQL queries like SELECT statements or conditional WHERE statements but not for creating tables.